# call querySelectorAll function in Apex XML Parser?

Tags: apex, xml

I have the following XML stored in a field from API,

I need to extract this data to store it as records to related list of the current object.

```
<steps id="0" last="9">
    <compref id="6" ref="90">
        <compref id="4" ref="89">
            <step id="7" type="ActionStep">
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 003</parameterizedString>
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 003</parameterizedString>
            </step>
            <compref id="8" ref="91">
                <step id="9" type="ActionStep">
                    <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 005</parameterizedString>
                    <parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 005</parameterizedString>
                </step>
            </compref>
        </compref>
    </compref>
</steps>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Array = [{step: 1, compref,        result:ref-90 },
         {step: 2, compref,        result:ref-89 },
         {step: 3, action:Stp 003, result:Act 003 },
         {step: 4, compref,        result:ref-91 },
         {step: 5, action:Stp 005, result: Act 005 }]
```

Already achieved via JavaScript,

```
const strXML = '<steps id="0" last="9"><compref id="6" ref="90"><compref id="4" ref="89"><step id="7" type="ActionStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 003</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 003</parameterizedString></step><compref id="8" ref="91"><step id="9" type="ActionStep"><parameterizedString isformatted="true">Stp 005</parameterizedString><parameterizedString isformatted="true">Act 005</parameterizedString></step></compref></compref></compref></steps>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(strXML, "text/xml");
const nodes = [...xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("steps *")];
var stepData = new Array();
nodes.filter(function(value) {
   if (value.tagName == "compref") {
      stepData.push({
         step: stepData.length + 1,
         action: "compref",
         result: value.getAttribute("ref")
      });
   }
   else if (value.tagName == "step") {
      stepData.push({
         step: stepData.length + 1,
         action: value.querySelectorAll("parameterizedString")[0].textContent,
         result: value.querySelectorAll("parameterizedString")[1].textContent
      });
   }
});
console.log(stepData);
```

But how to do this in [APEX XML Parser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_xml_dom.htm) ?

Is there any other way to parse this XML and update the related list whenever a change happens in this field?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the built-in parser directly, I'd suggest finding an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) implementation, such as [this one](https://github.com/JenniferSimonds/apex-xpath). Using a parser means that you have to keep track of the state yourself. You're much better off using an XPath-based implementation.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox, it didn't work if my out tags were different, I built my own class and it's working as expected. please feel free to add your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with XPath but it does work properly if you have an unknown/different structure. So I used a native built-in parser class to achieve the same way I wanted.

```
public class XMLStepParser {

    public static List<Step> Steps = new List<Step>();

    public class Step {
        public Integer stepNum { get; set;}
        public String action  { get; set; }
        public String result  { get; set; }
    }

    public static List<Step> parserXML(String strXML) {
        Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
        doc.load(strXML);
        Dom.XmlNode xroot = doc.getRootElement();
        getChildNodes(xroot);
        return Steps;
    }

    public static void getChildNodes(Dom.XmlNode node) {
        Dom.XmlNode[] nodeChilds = node.getChildElements();
        if(node.getName() == 'step') {
            Step stp = new Step();
            stp.stepNum = Steps.size();
            stp.action = nodeChilds[0].getText();
            stp.result = nodeChilds[1].getText();
            Steps.add(stp);
        } else if(node.getName() == 'compref') {
            Step stp = new Step();
            stp.stepNum = Steps.size()+1;
            stp.action = '*Shared Step';
            stp.result = node.getAttribute('ref','');
            Steps.add(stp);
        }
        for(Dom.XmlNode childNode: nodeChilds) {
            getChildNodes(childNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Exec:

```
system.Debug( XMLStepParser.parserXML(strXML) );
```